Bounds on the volume of the image of a cube, through bounds on area of cross sections
Let $f:[0,1]^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ be a smooth map. Assume that for every “vertical” affine plane $F=\{(a,b)\}\times [0,1]^2$, Area$(f[F])< a$. Assume also that for every “horizontal” affine plane $E= [0,1]^2 \times   \{(a’,b’)\}$, Area$(f[E])< a$. Is it true then that Vol$(f[[0,1]^4])<C\cdot a^2$, where $C>0$ is some global constant depending on the dimension of the setup?
For the analogue problem with $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, and Length$(f[F]) $,Length$(f[E])< a$ for every vertical line $F$ and horizontal line $E$, this is true by the triangle inequality and by bounding $f[[0,1]^2]$ in a ball.
Thanks in advance to all the helpers
